# Minimal surface and Gauss map

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I am struggling for an exercice in differential geometry :

S is a minimal surface if and only if the Gauss map $N : S \rightarrow S^2$ satisfies for all $p \in S$ and all $\omega_1, \omega_2 \ T_p(S)$ :
$$\langle dN_p(\omega_1),dN_p(\omega_2)\rangle = \lambda(p) \langle \omega_1, \omega_2 \rangle $$
where $\lambda(p)≠ 0$

I tried to use the fact that The mean curvature $H(p) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{eG + gE -2Ff}{EG -F^2}$. But I don't really see a link with this.

If someone can help me it would be great ! Thank you in advance

Comment: **HINT**: Write down the characteristic polynomial of $dN_p\colon T_pS\to T_pS$. (P.S. If you search this site, you'll find this question answered several times before.)

Comment: Yes thank you very much, I found it out !!